# Linking Storage folder without using Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-artisan

Please I need help in linking my storage folder manually without artisan.

I tried duplicating the folder manually in my root public directory, but it seems that I will also need to have the file uploaded both in the storage and the root directory storage.

Please How do I go around this as I know that Linking the file with artisan; there would be no need for the files also going into the root public storage.

PS: 
1. I can't run Artisan on my Server(Shared Hosting + No SSH)
2. I am avoiding duplicates files being uploaded so as to avoid consumption of disk space on my server.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` generates a the `public/storage` folder and symlinks it to `storage/app/public`, so simply do the same on your server. Any files uploaded into `storage/app/public` will be mirrored in `public/storage` and available via `http://yourapp.com/public/{file.ext}`

Comment: Create a setup route where you can call Artisan::call('storage:link');